# Magento2 http: to convert https: site stop working

Tags: magento2, https

I have follow below step https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-set-up-magento-2-to-use-your-ssl-certificate.html

but i am getting below error

> The web page at https://m2.key.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: try to flush and clean cache and reindexing.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: try to echo print in index.php file. check index.php file is called or not.

Comment: yes checked not working

Comment: Are you using any proxy ? ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED error is a usually a proxy error , try to disable any proxy or vpn if you are using any , also check that the problem occur on every browser .

Comment: @Radwan I have check removing proxy
and it's giving below error

Comment: Error: The requested resource could not be loaded. libcurl returned the error: Failed to connect to magento2.keynoteslides.com port 443: Connection refused

Comment: @RutveeSojitra that means port 443 is not open in your server , check your server if port 443 is open .

Comment: @Radwan thank you so much
Have you know how to make it open in dev server(linux)

Comment: @RutveeSojitra , what kind of hosting are you using ? most of the hosting providers has this opened by default , so maybe your problem is that you have no virtual host in your server config that listen to port 443 , do you have Cpanel on the server ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83436/discussion-between-rutvee-sojitra-and-radwan).

Comment: @RutveeSojitra you are welcome :) , glad you could solve it , please accept it as an answer .

Comment: you havn't post as answer how can accept

Comment: please add in answer wil be sure do that

Comment: what solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing SSL on Magento2 is so simple.. You can Install your SSL by cpanel and simply change the base url and secure base url from Magento2 Admin Panel stores->settings->configuration->general->web

After changing just do these commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of solving this issue:

Manually add the entry for `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml`  into the core_config_data  Add the following SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope,scope_id,path,value) VALUES ('default',0,'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml',1);
```

Change the URL in the table back to `HTTP://your.domain.com/.`

Clear the cache in both the cases by deleting /var/cache.

Comment: I want to make https url then why have to do http?

Comment: I know but u can try it

Comment: have tried not working

Comment: For that in your database make some changes in core_config_data table.

In table search "web/" from "search" tab in the header (using phpMyAdmin or similar). Edit web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url and
paste the URL of your site.

After that set value 0 to web/secure/use_in_frontend and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra try this in db side

Comment: you are going reverse

Comment: I want https and you are suggesting me http

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: is it work for you?

Comment: how can it's works?  it's wrong